# Symmetric encryption using Dukpt

Tags: c#, encryption-symmetric

I am new to this forum. Recently I am tasked to decrypt a file that is encrypted using AES encryption( which require a secret key for encryption and decryption as well). File use to encrypt in every 5 minute using a DUKPT .

I am working on c# .By searching around on Google, i have found how to decrypt file if you have got DUKPT. but I don't know how to generate DUKPT using Key Serial Number(KSN)  and Base Derivation Key(BDK). Is there any library support in c# by which we can generate DUKPT..

Hoping a great help here

DUKPT: Derived unique key per transaction

Comment: Is there no one available on this forum

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sgbj/Dukpt.NET - Great introduction. You'll need the specification to understand the code as it was written with clever brevity in mind, not readability. I used it 6 months ago to not only learn about DUKPT, but to implement the embedded C libraries for biometric sensor device.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in last post ANSI standard that defines DUKPT, X9.24-1 in 3DES mode, that means Dukpt uses 3DES algorithm to generate Key(not to encrypt or decrypt data) and it is known as 3DES-DUKPT.Another type is AES-DUKPT, which uses AES-ECB mode to generate key.
Both have common inputs Base derivation Key(BDK) and KSN with different size.
For 3DES-DUKPT, BDK = 16 bytes(always) and KSN = 10 bytes.
For AES-DUKPT, BDK = 16, 24, 32 bytes(depend upon AES key size) and KSN = 12 bytes.

Input KSN consist of Key_serial_number and Counter.

Input BDK and Key_serial_number (from KSN) generates IPEK.
And IPEK with Counter(from KSN) generates Encryption / Decryption key for data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ANSI standard that defines DUKPT, X9.24-1 but that uses DES both for the encryption/decryption and to produce the keys.  Since you said BDK and KSN, I imagine this is what you have in mind.  I expect you did not get any responses (even after the extended period of four hours) because you said AES and DUKPT in the same posting.  (People in the know read that and say, RTFM.)

It is not C# but I believe there is a DUKPT.m file by "Mikhail Burshteyn" pointed to on Stack Exchange or somewhere in the last six months or so.  There is also pieces of code in C that I wrote to illustrate how to decrypt. (Something that is not covered worth a darn in the standard.)

If you want source code in C# that you can cut and paste, I think you will be disappointed.